# Inserting Shortcode into WooCommerce Product Description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks, wordpress-shortcode

We need to add shortcode into the WooCommerce Product Description. The intent is that we can call blocks into specific products and just update that block vs. the each individual listing. Any idea how to do so? Currently it just shows the actual shortcode, not the content.

This is the shortcode: `[block id="product-callouts-01"]`

I tried this code in my Functions.php file, but to no avail:

```
if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_single_excerpt')) {
   function woocommerce_template_single_excerpt( $post ) {
       global $post;
       if ($post->post_excerpt) echo '<div itemprop="description">' . do_shortcode(wpautop(wptexturize($post->post_excerpt))) . '</div>';
   }
}
```

Comment: You should provide your code in your question, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Is it for product description or for product **short** description (excerpt)?

Comment: Product description (main one)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code to your function.php

```php
function custom_woocommerce_product_description($description) {

    $pattern = '/\[block id="([^\]]+)"\]/'; 
    if (preg_match($pattern, $description, $matches)) {
        $shortcode = $matches[0];
        $block_id = $matches[1];

        $block_content = get_block_content_by_id($block_id); 
        $description = str_replace($shortcode, $block_content, $description);
    }

    return do_shortcode($description);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'custom_woocommerce_product_description');

function get_block_content_by_id($block_id) {
    $block_content = "Replace this with the actual content of the block";

    return $block_content;
}

?>
```

Comment: When you say "replace this with actual content of the block", are you referring to the text in the block or the shortcode? We don't want to be having to edit the functions file each time when making changes to the block.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To add a shortcode to the product description, you can try the following:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_product_description' );
function change_product_description( $post_content ) {
    global $post;

    if( get_post_type($post->ID) === 'product' ) {
        $post_content .= do_shortcode('[block id="product-callouts-01"]');
    }
    return $post_content;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: This is bringing back the following error: "Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function change_product_description()"

Comment: @IVCatalina Sorry I have updated my answer code...